# How to concatenate sliced array to a list in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I am trying to merge a sliced array to a list in Python but i get an

```
 error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes `(4,)` `(2,)` .
```

This is my code:

```
y = np.array([5,3,2,4,6,1])
row = y[2:6] + np.array([0,0])
```

I am expecting to get a 2-item shifted vector to the left and last 2 items being assigned to 0.

Comment: `y[2:6] + list(np.array([0,0]))`?

Comment: `+` for a list is concatenate, but for an array it is addition (and has priority).

Comment: What is the output you’re looking for? (Please update the question with expected output).

Comment: You can also use [numpy concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate arrays use `np.concatenate`:

```
In [93]: y = np.array([5,3,2,4,6,1])
In [94]: y[2:6]
Out[94]: array([2, 4, 6, 1])
In [95]: np.concatenate((y[2:6], np.array([0,0])))
Out[95]: array([2, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0])
```

`+` is concatenate for lists.  For arrays is addition (numeric sum).

Your question should not have used `list` and `array` in a sloppy manner.  They are different things (in python/numpy) and can produce confusing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy array works something like a matrix. So when you try to apply the addition operation to a numpy array, you're actually performing an "element-wise addition". That's why the value you add with a numpy array must be the same dimension as the numpy array. Otherwise such a value that can be broadcasted.

Notice the example to understand what I'm saying.

Adding two lists with addition sign:

```
>>> [1,2] + [3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Adding two numpy arrays:

```
>>> np.array([1,2]) + np.array([3,4])
array([4, 6])
```

To get your work done, use the `np.append(arr, val, axis)` function. [Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.append([1,2], np.array([3,4]))
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

For concatenation, you will need to convert your numpy array to a list first.

`row = y[2:6] + list(np.array([0,0]))`

or equivalently

`row = y[2:6] + np.array([0,0]).tolist()`

However, if you wish to add the two (superpose a list and numpy array), then the numpy array just needs to be the same shape as y[2:6]:

```
In : y[2:6] + np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out: array([y[2] + 1, y[3] + 2, y[4] + 3, y[5] + 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already explain why your code fail. You can do:

```
out = np.zeros_like(y)
out[:-2] = y[2:]
```

Output:

```
array([2, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0])
```